# What is wrong with my coffeescript in Stripe?

Tags: coffeescript, stripe-payments

I've been working on integrating Stripe into my web application, and it doesn't seem to be working. To help me along, I've been using Ryan Bates's Rails Cast on integrating Stripe. Whenever I try to run the payment form, I get an error saying that "There was a problem with my credit card". I think the problem lies in my coffeescript file, but perhaps I'm wrong. I've included the stripe user token as a part of my user model instead of placing it into its own subscription model. Here is the coffeescript code I have:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  subscription.setupForm()

user =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_user').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        user.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, user.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 500
      $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      $('#new_user')[0].submit()
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming, so any help you can give me would be great.

Here's the error I get in my terminal when I try to sign up:

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xas+iA+a3op7jUi57qTr7XWQSClPscA7fR19rkclkEE=", "user"=>{"stripe_card_token"=>"", "name"=>"Jack", "email"=>"email@example.com", "phone_number"=>"203-xxx-xxxx", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}

User Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('jjets718@yahoo.com') LIMIT 1
Stripe error while creating customer: Invalid token id:

My view for the signup is this:

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

            <%= f.hidden_field :stripe_card_token %>

            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :phone_number, "Your cell phone number" %>
            <%= f.text_field :phone_number %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Password confirmation" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= label_tag :card_number, "Credit Card Number" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_number, nil, name: nil %>

            <%= label_tag :card_code, "Security Code on Card (CVV)" %>
            <%= text_field_tag :card_code, nil, name: nil %>

            <%= label_tag :card_month, "Card Expiration" %>
            <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month"}%>
        <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: nil, id: "card_year"} %>

    <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>

<div id="stripe_error">
  <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
</div>
```

My code for my controller is this for the create method:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    if @user.save_with_payment
     sign_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
     redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
     UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

My code for the database migration for the user token is this:

```
class AddStripeToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :stripe_customer_token, :string
  end
end
```

And the code for the save_with_payment method in my model is this:

```
 def save_with_payment
     if valid?
       customer = Stripe::Customer.create(description: email, plan: 1, card: stripe_card_token)
       self.stripe_customer_token = customer.id
       save!
     end

   rescue Stripe::InvalidRequestError => e
     logger.error "Stripe error while creating customer: #{e.message}"
     errors.add :base, "There was a problem with your credit card."
     false
   end
```

Comment: What `status` and `response` are you getting back and what makes you think your CoffeeScript rather than your card information is the problem?

Comment: In stripe, my account is currently in test mode, and I'm using the card code: 4242424242424242, the cvc code:123, and an expiration date past today's month. I don't get an application error, but just an error that the card information is incorrect. I'm going to add the error I get in my terminal to the original question. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Why are you checking `status == 500` as a success condition? That means that there was a server error on Stripe's servers. You should be checking `if(!response.error)`. You noticed that `stripe_card_token` is empty on your server, right?

Comment: So if(!response.error) should replace if status == 500? When I make that change stripe_card_token is still empty. Or is there another way to make it work? Do you that the error is in my model or controller?

Comment: What does `console.log response` have to say inside `handleStripeResponse`? You do have an `id="card_number"` element in your HTML, right?

Comment: I just added my signup view, the relevant methods in my user model and controller, and my db migration for stripe. Perhaps the error is in there somewhere? Thanks again for all of your help on this!

Comment: Have you checked the HTML (not the ERB) to make sure everything is where you expect it to be and the `id` attributes are right? Have you looked at the `response` object that you get back from Stripe?

Comment: I don't get a response object from Stripe. When the form doesn't work, the only two references that are made to Stripe in my terminal are these: "stripe_card_token"=>"", and Stripe error while creating customer: Invalid token id:.

Comment: I'm confused. Is `user.processCard()` getting called at all? Which branch of the `if $('#card_number').length` does it go through? I'd "join you in chat" but I'm on and off line this evening.

Comment: I'm not sure which branch it goes through. Do you mind if I add you to my repo on Github as it might make it easier to resolve this issue? I can't thank you enough for all of the help you are providing.

Comment: I am having this exact problem....can you update with an answer please :/

Answer (score 0):

2 things that come to mind:

1. You should be doing a status check for 200, not 500
2. You may need to require the coffeescript file in your application.js

   - e.g. //= require users

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but at this point:

```
handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
  if status == 500
    $('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
```

In addition to changing `if status == 500` to `if status == 200`, this line `$('#user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)` may need to be `$('#new_user_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)`. Make sure to check the input ID.