# How to track down the cause of an error in coffescript and Stripe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe in my Rails 3 application to do creditcard payments. I'm roughly following the [railscast on Stripe integration](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) though my app is doing just a single charge for now and not subscription billing like Ryan shows.

The problem is, I can't get the `processCard()` function to fire. I'll be the first to admit I'm not a javascript guru (or any kind of guru for that matter). It doesn't give a javascript error, it instead submits the form to rails (without any credit card details) and fails since `stripe_card_token` is nil. I've placed some `alert()` dialogs spaced throughout for some very crude debugging to see where the hangup is. My model name is `Payment` which is really the only deviation so far from Ryan's code apart from the temporary alert() dialogs.

So my question is twofold: How can I reliably track down what's causing the problem? and Where did I go wrong?

Here's the Javascript:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  payment.setupForm()

payment =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#new_payment').submit ->
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      alert("before processCard")
      payment.processCard()
      alert("after processCard")
      false
      # else
      #   true

  processCard: ->
    alert("processCard start")
    card =
      number: $('#credit_card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#cvc').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    alert("card values are set")
    Stripe.createToken(card, payment.handleStripeResponse)
    alert("After createToken")

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      alert(response.id)
      # $('#payment_stripe_card_token').val(response.id)
      # $('#new_payment')[0].submit()
    else
      alert(response.error.message)
      # $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      # $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

And the associated view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @payment, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal'} do |f| %>
<fieldset>
  <legend>Pay via Credit Card</legend>

    <%= f.input :stripe_card_token, :as => :hidden, :id => 'stripe_card_token' %>

    <div class="well well-small">
      <%= current_user.full_name %><br />
      <%= current_user.email %><br />
      This is the name we have on file for you. If it's not correct, please <%= link_to "change it now", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
    </div>

<div id="stripe_error">
  <noscript>JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.</noscript>
</div>

<div id="credit-card">
  <div class="control-group string required">
    <%= label_tag :credit_card_number, "Card Number", :class => "control-label string required" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= text_field_tag :credit_card_number, nil, :class => "string required", :name => nil %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group string required">
    <%= label_tag :cvc, "Security code (CVC)", :class => "control-label string required" %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= text_field_tag :cvc, nil, :class => "string required", :name => nil %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="control-group date required">
    <%= label_tag :card_month, "Expiration Date", :class => "control-label date required"%>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: nil, id: "card_month", :class => "date required span2"} %>
      <%= select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+25}, {name: nil, id: "card_year", :class => "date required span2"} %>
    </div>
  </div>

    <h4>Your unpaid courses</h4>
    <% @unpaid_subs.each do |sub| %>
      <%= sub.course.name %>&nbsp;|&nbsp;<%= sub.course.credits %><br />
    <% end %>

<div class="form-actions">
<%= f.submit nil, :class=>"btn btn-primary" %>
<%= link_to "Cancel", courses_path, :class=>"btn" %>
</div>
</fieldset>
<% end %>
```

Related Question(No accepted answer): [What is wrong with my CoffeScript in Stripe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314013)

Comment: Does `setupForm` get called? Consider the difference between http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Apcfa/ and http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/BRp6S/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It does get called because the `alert("before processCard") shows up.

Comment: Have you looked at the HTML that `simple_form_for` generates? Maybe you don't have the right selector, maybe `simple_form_for` is doing something odd behind your back.

Comment: Yeah, I double checked the selectors. I had them wrong before for selecting the form, but I corrected it with no improvement. The id for the form tag is `#new_payment`

Comment: Are you sure that there's no other JavaScript getting in your way? Restart by writing the HTML by hand and getting rid of all (Coffee|Java)Script except the stripe libraries, jQuery, and your code.

Comment: Before I read your comment, I was able to get it to run the `processCard` function, but it gets hung up and `createToken` now. I know it's not very helpful, but I don't know what I did to get that part to start working. I replaced the simple_form_for with just the basic html as shown on the Stripe documentation (modifying id's to match). No improvement.

Comment: Ok, I found an inline javascript for initializing a modal from Twitter bootstrap and removed it. It appears to be working now and gives the correct Stripe token. I'm now adding things back one at a time to see what's breaking it. I'll post back tomorrow with the results if I solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. Thanks a ton "@mu is too short". Your suggestion of stripping it down to just the required js and html ultimately helped me find the error.

It turns out I had misspelled the name attribute on my meta tag that has the Stripe public key. In the application layout, it was missing the "r" in "stripe-key":

```
<%= tag :meta, :name => "stipe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
```

I had a super hard time finding this since it didn't cause any exceptions or show up in the logs. To find the cause of the problem, I did two things:

- I placed `alert()` dialogs in key places of the javascript to pause the script as it runs and find which function wasn't working. Kind of crude, but it worked.
- As @mu is too short said in the comments:

> Are you sure that there's no other JavaScript getting in your way? Restart by writing the
>   HTML by hand and getting rid of all (Coffee|Java)Script except the stripe libraries,
>   jQuery, and your code.

In doing this, I found that the javascript won't run  properly if there is an error in some other javascript on the page. By stripping the view down to just the essentials, I not only ultimately found the problem with the variable name, but also found several unrelated errors.